# Removed and reinstalled Anaconda on my AWS Deep Learning AMI EC2 instance and now can't enter preconfigured deep learning environments

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, installation, anaconda, amazon-ami

I've just set up an Ubuntu Deep Learning AMI EC2 instance. I'm a total beginner on AWS/package handling stuff.

My aim is to use the instance to execute a Python deep learning script. This script uses a variety of packages.

When installing some of these packages with conda, I got an error stating environment inconsistencies for 100+ packages. After many attempts to solve this, I thought removing Anaconda and reinstalling may do the trick. After doing this, I've realised I may have messed up my instance even more. I can now no longer use the preset deep learning environments the AMI has been configured for, as these were accessed using conda commands, which (IMO) I seem to have removed.

I've tried repeating the commands, but I am getting an error stating these environments no longer exist. A tutorial using these commands is mentioned here: 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dlami/latest/devguide/tutorial-conda.html

```sh
source activate tensorflow_p36
```

I expected the above to enter me into the tensorflow_p36 environment. As in:

```sh
(tensorflow_p36) ubuntu@ip-XXX-XX-XX-XX:~/scripts
```

However it gives an error message:

```sh
could not find environment: tensorflow_p36
```

I realise uninstalling conda was a major rookie error which seems to have totally disabled my instance. If anyone has any ideas to salvage it that would be much appreciated!

Thanks very much

Comment: I think you'd be better off starting from a fresh instance. First, activate the conda environment that is closest to what you need (e.g. 'source activate tensorflow_p36') and then install the packages that you're missing ('pip install ...'). What other problems were you facing?

Comment: Yep, I ended up starting a new instance. I was having issues with package inconsistencies when trying to rebuild the env. Got it all working now though - thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly your question, but if anybody else is thinking about uninstalling conda from the deep learning AMI because it seems insane, this might help.

The AWS Deep Learning AMIs is configured in a way that makes it refuse to install conda environments that work reliably on other machines.  This seems to fix the problem for me:

```bash
conda config --set channel_priority false
```

(This is maybe obvious to conda-heads, but confounded me for a while, so hopefully this helps somebody else.)